# Ontop dialogue box. change colour of background: (EDIT) to Entire doc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, re-sized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

Displays a dialogue box on screen, ontop of the page you are viewing.

I would like to grey out the background page while the dialogue box is appearing.  I've looked through the documentation but I don't see any reference to background colour.

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the help guys...This has resolved the problem however I have just discovered that if the user scrolls down the screen while the dialog box is visible, the new part of the page being displayed will be grey'd out.

This modal:true only seems to apply to what is currently being viewed - Does anyone know of a way to apply it to the entire page?
Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `modal` property to true (as shown in the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)):

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true
    });
});
```

Comment: This answer is correct but iv discovered a error, please see my edit.

Comment: Your edit isn't clear. You say 'new part is gray'd out' and 'how to apply it to the entire page'. So what's the problem exactly? Is the whole page gray and you don't want that, or is only part of the page (i.e. only the visible part) grayed out and when you scroll some other parts are actually visible?

Comment: The second part to what you said is happening...only part of the page (i.e. only the visible part) grayed out and when you scroll some other parts are actually visible.

Comment: Actually, it's a bit strange. Check your `jquery-ui.css` file. It should have `position: fixed` on style `.ui-widget-overlay`. That way, the whole viewport should be covered and the overlay should stay in place because of its `fixed` position.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog({modal: true});
 });
</script>
```

Basically modal:true tells the widget if it has to show some overlay in the background or it will be opened as a simple dialog box.

You can find documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-modal)

Comment: Sorry i had to un-answer this as iv discovered a error, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at background css, it has `ui-widget-overlay` class:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    background: #aaaaaa/*{bgColorOverlay}*/ url(images/ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_40x100.png)/*{bgImgUrlOverlay}*/ 50%/*{bgOverlayXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgOverlayYPos}*/ repeat-x/* {bgOverlayRepeat}*/;
    opacity: .3/*{opacityOverlay}*/;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=30)/*{opacityFilterOverlay}*/;
}
```

change it...

Comment: Thanks for the help but i now have a further problem. Please see my edit

Comment: @John write position: fixed in css